# How to average a column and use half the values if they are below a certain value (all in 1 column)?

Tags: excel-formula, median

I am struggling with writing an Excel formula without errors to calculate average and median of a numeric column, however if certain values are less than, I want to use half the value in the formula.

Example dataset:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1 | 5 |
| Day 2 | 10 |
| Day 3 | 5 |
| Day 4 | 25 |
| Day 5 | 41 |

Average of B = `17.2`

If value is equal or less than 5, I want to half this value. The Average value I am trying to replicate is: `16.2`

I've tried `AVERAGEIF`, `AVERAGEIFS`, `AVERAGE (IF=)` combinations and I always get some sort of error.

I've been able to successfully calculate average for the halved values, or not valued, but not an equation to combine both.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B9:B71,B9:B71,"<="&5)
```

What do I need to add to my formula to make it work? Any help is much appreciated!

I've tried AVERAGEIF, AVERAGEIFS, AVERAGE (IF=) combinations and I always get some sort of error.

I've been able to successfully calculate average for the halved values, or not valued, but not an equation to combine both.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B9:B71,B9:B71,"<="&5)
```

PS-excel for microsoft 365

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B1:B5<=5,B1:B5/2,B1:B5))
```

The if will return an array of the value or the value divided by 2 if the value is less than or equal to 5.

[image]